# I want to execute code when a the user selects an item in a DataGridViewComboBox column in a Windows Form

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a windows forms application with a DataGridView This DataGridView  has a DataGridViewComboBox column.  I want to react when the user makes a selection from the combo box, but before the user moves out of that cell.  Is there event that fires at that time?

Comment: can u please show ur effort

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, I can only give a general answer. You need to trap the EditControlShowing event. Within the EditControlShowing function, you need to enable handlers to what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this a different way.  I changed the cell to a text cell and display a standalone combo box above or below the cell (depending on relative position of the cell in the container) when the user clicks in the cell (which is read only).  I can then react to the combo box events which fire as I expect.